# jruleImportException : the selected archive does not have descriptor.xml

Tags: datastage, odm

I have created JAR file from decision service in IBM ODM. I was using that into datastage application to call rule app from datastage. while doing that I am getting error.

JruleImoprtException: the selected archive "filePath" is not valid ruleset archive.the file descriptor.xml could not be located in the archive.

I have used 8.10 version to create decision service. Datastage is using 8.8 version.

Is it creating error because of the conflicting version or I have created jar file wrong way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM has moved to Decision service from 8.10 onwards that uses Decision rule engine to creates dsar file for deployment. This dsar file has archive.xml to instruct the Jrule connector about the information of the rules.

In earlier versions - Rule projects are created using classic rule engine and jar file is required to deploy the project. In those version it has description.xml file that contains the metadata about the projects parameters.
As of now, you can switch to Classic Rule Engine option to create a JAR file that includes the description.xml. It is deprecated so not advisable.

In Eclipse -> Right click on the project -> Rule Execution server -> Select classic rule engine.